# How to install a new component version automatically during development

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I develop my first full component, following my tutorial. When I reached a point for check I do some steps:

- create the zip file
- open the backend tab in my browser
- click on "browse installation file"
- click on the file
- click ok
- click on upload & install

These are a lot of clicks for the upload of a version. I would like to do this more automatic. The zip-file is created via "grunt", but I can't figure out how to send this file to the install process of my local Joomla installation.

Answer (score 2):

One:
The quick option is to create ANT build script which will automatically copy files to respective directories as and when they are edited. Eclipse can handle this for you effortlessly. Some sample ANT build script for XAMPP installation here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Test" default="copyall" basedir=".">
    <property name="site3" value="d:/xampp/htdocs/j3/components/com_mycom" />
    <property name="admin3" value="d:/xampp/htdocs/j3/administrator/components/com_mycom" />
    <property name="sitelang3" value="d:/xampp/htdocs/j3/language/en-GB" />
    <property name="adminlang3" value="d:/xampp/htdocs/j3/administrator/language/en-GB" />
    <property name="media3" value="d:/xampp/htdocs/j3/media/com_mycom" />

    <target name="copyall">
        <copy todir="${site3}"><fileset dir="site"><include name="**"/></fileset></copy>
        <copy todir="${admin3}" ><fileset dir="admin"><include name="**" /><exclude name="language/**"/></fileset></copy>
        <copy todir="${sitelang3}"><fileset dir="site/language/en-GB"><include name="**"/></fileset></copy>
        <copy todir="${adminlang3}"><fileset dir="admin/language/en-GB"><include name="**"/></fileset></copy>
        <copy todir="${media3}"><fileset dir="site/media"><include name="**"/></fileset></copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Two:
The next quick option is use directory installer. It will avoid 3 clicks i.e. for zip and upload.

Comment: I think that the combination of these two answers will work: for smaller changes only the ANT script will copy the files, and with any larger changes (database, version number) I need to do the installation.