# Is there a way to automate component installation in a build script?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, extensions, external-script

I have a build script that watches the files in the component for activity, and automatically zips up the component, and overwrites the existing zip. I still have to manually go to the admin interface and install the component.

This as most of you probably know, takes a little time, that adds up considerably.

Is there a way to script the component installation process, so that I don't have to do this. I'm hoping to avoid having to script a scraper to open the page and go through the process, as this seems a bit heavy-handed to me.

Comment: Would this be of use? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-to-install-a-new-component-version-automatically-during-development

Comment: Okay, quick question in the comments section. If the script just copies the files and folders, into where they go in the project, is there any reason not to just edit them in place, and then zip/install them when I get my desired result?

Comment: If there are no database changes or the component can update the database schema from an sql file and caching is off, it should not be an issue. Some components might do weird things and it might mess with updater, but if you are developing your own component, go ahead.